# How to Convert PDF File into Image File using ImageMagick

Tags: c#, pdf, imagemagick

How should I convert pdf file into image (.jpg, .gif etc) using `ImageMagick` on c# programming platform? or is there any third party library aside from `ImageMagick` that can be used to do this?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176183/how-to-convert-pdf-to-images-using-c-sharp-and-imagemagick and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916555/converting-pdf-to-images-using-imagemagick-net-how-to-set-the-dpi and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/efb56ede-c588-4ac0-97cd-3a54205a885d/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ghostscript](http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/) can read PDF (as well as PostScript and EPS) and convert it to many different image formats.

*BTW, ImageMagick cannot do that itself -- ImageMagick also utilizes Ghostscript for exactly that conversion as an external 'delegate'. ImageMagick is great for continuing to process and manipulate image files -- at which jobs it really excels!

The command `gs -h` (or on Windows: `gswin32c.exe -h`) should give you an overview about the different *devices* that are built into your Ghostscript:

```
GPL Ghostscript GIT PRERELEASE 9.05 (2011-03-30)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
Usage: gs [switches] [file1.ps file2.ps ...]
Most frequently used switches: (you can use # in place of =)
 -dNOPAUSE           no pause after page   | -q       `quiet', fewer messages
 -g<width>x<height>  page size in pixels   | -r<res>  pixels/inch resolution
 -sDEVICE=<devname>  select device         | -dBATCH  exit after last file
 -sOutputFile=<file> select output file: - for stdout, |command for pipe,
                                         embed %d or %ld for page #
Input formats: PostScript PostScriptLevel1 PostScriptLevel2 PostScriptLevel3 PDF
Default output device: x11alpha
Available devices:
   alc1900 [....] bmp16 bmp16m [...]
   bmp256 bmp32b bmpgray bmpmono bmpsep1 bmpsep8 [....] jpeg jpegcmyk jpeggray 
   pamcmyk32 pamcmyk4 pbm pbmraw pcl3 pcx16 pcx24b [....]
   pcx256 pcx2up pcxcmyk pcxgray pcxmono pdfwrite pgm pgmraw pgnm pgnmraw
   png16 png16m png256 png48 pngalpha
   pnggray pngmono pnm pnmraw ppm ppmraw [....] tiff12nc tiff24nc tiff32nc tiff48nc
   tiff64nc tiffcrle tiffg3 tiffg32d tiffg4 tiffgray tifflzw tiffpack
   tiffscaled tiffscaled24 tiffscaled8 tiffsep tiffsep1 [....]
```

So, to create a series of PNGs from the multipage PDF *my_pdf.pdf* with a certain image size (I chose DIN A4 paper format at 72 dpi) and resolution, use the *pngalpha* device. Try this command:

```
 gswin32c ^
    -o my_pdf_page_%03d.png ^
    -sDEVICE=pngalpha ^
    -dPDFFitPage ^
    -g595x842 ^
    -r72x72 ^
     my_pdf.pdf
```